# apache auth and file_get_contents on self

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, file-get-contents

I've got a line of code - which we cannot change that is

`$preview = file_get_contents( SITE_URL . "/preview" );`

I've got a vhost.conf/htaccess with the following

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs>
        Require valid-user
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from internal-domain.com
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

This is working fine regards to accessing the webapp

However when the file_get_contents runs, its triggering the apache auth - thus failing

```
[Tue Mar 17 11:20:20 2015] [error] [client 178.97.118.254] file_get_contents(http://domain.com/preview): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n
```

I cant figure out how to white-list the server from itself regarding this.

I've tried using the hostname, 127.0.0.1, localhost, external ip in an `Allow from` but they all keep requesting authentication.

How can I allow the server to bypass itself by white-listing it within the vhost.conf?

Comment: So you tried "Allow from 178.97.118.254"?

Comment: Nope, that was just my 3G IP from my phone, but I tried from our internet network which IP was in the list, and changed nothing

Comment: If safe, temporarily remove the restrictions on the directory (only if safe to do so). At least then you can rule out those settings. If not safe on that directory, create another directory for the test.

Comment: If I comment out all the lines so there's no authentication at all it works absolutely fine and as expected

Comment: ok good. Now check the access log. Look for the request just like you found your 3G one and allow the IP address it lists. Whatever ip is listed is the one Apache is using when it authorizes the request. It could be the servers public ip

Comment: Very strange hostname its kicking out id22023 but after allowing that in the whitelist, it did infact allow it through! thanks